# mod_rewrite code not passing parameters in the URL

Tags: .htaccess

The purpose of this rewrite code is to change the URL to include www on the URI request and pass everything else to it. I'm finding that the URL parameters are not being passed on.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by permeters not being passed? what url are you going to and what do you expect to happe

Comment: Any and all HTTP post variables passed by a URL

Comment: Not following - are you talking about `POST` variables? As in from a form?

Comment: `/product_info.php?products_id=10183` as an example

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have more rules?

Comment: Maybe it's the `[QSA]` parameter?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]`